# Can you connect to WebRTC server to get the video stream from python?

Tags: webrtc, raspberry-pi3, uv4l

I'm trying to get the video feed from usb camera attached to my Raspberry. Since it's not the dedicated one I can't just use raspivid or the raspicam that comes with uv4l to make changes to config that actually gives some effect at contrary to v4l2-ctl.

When I connect to the WebRTC server through the browser client it actually works at decent framerate. I don't yet understand how that technology works, but before jumping into it I was wondering if someone could tell me if it's possible to somehow (with client made in python or some other opencv magic) get that video feed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm still interested if what I've talk about is possible, so if anyone with knowledge stumbles upon this thread, please let me know.

I've kinda solved my issue by using the mjpg-streamer experimental instead, it can be found here:

```
https://github.com/jacksonliam/mjpg-streamer
```

Now I'm getting over 8 fps, but it seems much more constant and really seems like I don't need more, compared to uv4l that gave me 3.5 fps with stutters.